# applying rotation and speed to move user

Tags: mathematics, geometry

My player has a position (vec3), rotation (quaternion) and speed.

I have a fixed time step.  At each tick, I work out from key-state etc what rotation and speed adjustments to make.

How do I now compute the new position?

And how, for the graphics which run at a different framerate, do I compute the the tweening for smooth movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Rotation*Vector3::Forward).Normalize() * move_speed * dt

**dt** - time elapsed since last frame
**Vector3::Forward** - direction to move relative to current rotation.